# Не запускается приложение на смартфоне с Android Studio

Tags: android, android-studio

Пытаюсь запустить код приложения из Android Studio на Xiaomi redmi note 4, получаю окно с ошибкой:

> Installation failed with message Failed to establish session. It is possible that this issue is resolved by uninstalling an existing version of the apk if it is present, and then re-installing.

Кто сталкивался с подобным, подскажите, что с этим делать? Драйвера установлены, устройство видно в списке, JDK последний.

Comment: Ну а собственно совет из логов вашей ошибки пробовали? Ещё попробуйте `InstantRun` отключить

Answer (score 0, accepted):

У меня была аналогичная ситуация на `Xiaomi Redme Note 3 Pro`.

Проблема была во включенной оптимизации MIUI. Решилась так:

> Настройки --> Дополнительно --> Для разработчиков --> Выключить
>   оптимизацию MIUI (Settings --> Additional settings --> Developer
>   options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization)

или

> Настройки --> Дополнительно --> Для разработчиков --> Выключить
>   оптимизацию MIUI (Settings --> Developer options --> Turn Off MIUI optimization)

После этого перезагрузил телефон и все заработало =)

Comment: Не помогло(( у меня xiaomi redmi s2